# floating-box under- input

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website and per requeriments, there's one thing I can't manage to figure out the best way to implement.

https://www.lacestitadelbebe.es Take a look at this website. You can see there's a search form in the front page, the "c00l" thing about it, is that once you click on the field ("¿Que Buscas?"), it pops up a list of "suggestions". Or categoryes about related stuff.

I'm trying to accomplish the same behaviour, but avoiding loadings (I already have the information to be shown beforehand). I believe it could be accomplished by CSS and hidden divs or bootstrap. The thing is, I do not know how to accomplish that. How to popup a floating box under the exact position of the input box.

Could someone give me an example? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] - links to websites are only acceptable if you reproduce the problem in the question - this is meant to be a repository of information for future visitors and external links rot (or in your case would get fixed) so future users would not be able to see the original problem if the code is not in the question

Comment: have a look at autocomplete plugins - [jquery ui do a decent one](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score -1):

I used the free AJAX Autocomplete for jQuery library on a recent project and it works quite well:

https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Since you know the values beforehand, you can use pre-specified values, look for the "Local lookup (no ajax):" example on the page linked above.

Example: See the search box in the top right corner: https://dosgames.com All of the values are known beforehand.